# Pork roast defrost using calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am really stuck on this problem for calculus and I could use some help

A pork roast is removed from the freezer and left on the counter to defrost. The temperature of the pork roast was $−4^\circ C$ when it was removed from the freezer, and $t$ hours later was increasing at a rate of
$$T′(t)=8e^{−0.3t} \quad^\circ C\text{/hour}.$$

Assume the pork roast is defrosted when its temperature reaches $11^\circ C$.  How long does it take for the pork roast to defrost? (Estimate answer rounded off to 3 decimal places.)

I found the integral to be $$\frac{-80}{3} e^{-3(t/10)}+C$$ but I don't know where to go from here please help me if you can

Comment: Best title ever.

Comment: Does one of the answers help ? Please show any reaction.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed,
$$
\begin{split}
T(t) &= T(0) + \int_{s=0}^{s=t} T'(s) ds \\
     &= -4 + \int_{s=0}^{s=t} 8e^{-0.3s} ds \\
     &= -4 -\frac{8}{0.3} \left[e^{-0.3t} - 1\right] \\
     &= -4 + \frac{80}{3} \left[1 - e^{-0.3t}\right]
\end{split}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: to solve this then do I set it equal to the 11 degrees that is the end point and then solve for the t?

Comment: @user347789 correct

Comment: @gt6989b don't be in a hurry in re-editing, and complete the change also in $T'(s)$

Comment: @GCab could you have possibly not refreshed the page?

Comment: @gt6989b, well maybe it was just a question of web latency, pardon for that.

Comment: @GCab oknp thanks for trying to look for the little bugs -- much better when all is done properly

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is

$T(t) =-80/3e^{-0.3\cdot t}+C$

Now use the initial condition: $T(0)=-4$

$T(0)=-4 =-80/3\cdot e^{-0.3\cdot 0}+C$

$-4=-80/3\cdot 1+C$

$C=-4+80/3$

$C=-12/3+80/3=68/3$

Therefore $T(t)= -80/3e^{-0.3\cdot t}+68/3$

*Now you can set the equation to $11$.*

$T(t)=11= -80/3e^{-0.3\cdot t}+68/3$

$\underbrace{68/3-11}_{35/3}=80/3e^{-0.3\cdot t}$

$\frac{3}{80}\cdot \frac{35}{3}=e^{-0.3\cdot t}$

$\frac{7}{16}=e^{-0.3\cdot t}$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: OP's integral is equivalent to yours, $3/10 = 0.3$...

Comment: @gt6989b Yes, you´re right. Thanks for the comment.